# Amazon S3 javascript sdk for Browser throwing 403 error

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, electron, amazon-javascript-sdk

I am using Amazon s3 javascript sdk for one of my applications. I am getting the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
```

I see that the preflight requests are failing in my case.

I am using Angular2 for my application and I am trying to get the list of buckets. This is the code I wrote:

```
getBuckets(comp: any) {
        var s3 = this.getS3();
        var params = {};
        s3.listBuckets(params, function(err, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log('error from list buckets');
            }
            else {
                comp.buckets = response.Buckets;
            }
        })
    }
```

this.getS3() is a method I wrote to create an S3 instance. This is how it looks:

```
private getS3() {
        var currentUser = this.accountInfoService.getCurrentUser();
        AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: currentUser.accessKeyId, secretAccessKey: currentUser.secretAccessKey });
        var Logger = { log: function(line) { console.log(line) } };
        if (currentUser.isECS) {
            console.log(currentUser.isECS);
            var ep = new AWS.Endpoint('http://' + currentUser.endPoint);
            var s3 = new AWS.S3({ endpoint: ep, s3ForcePathStyle: true, logger: Logger, sslEnabled: false });
        }
        else {
            var s3 = new AWS.S3();
        }
        return s3;
    }
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Try to add the HTTP verb "OPTIONS" to the allowed request headers on the server. You need to add it in the response headers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't allow me to add the OPTIONS in the response header. It says, its not a supported method.

Comment: try as a header not as a method, you can add this <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader> to bypass the header restriction